# At/on/in a high level

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct preposition in this context?

*Everything was **at/on/in** a high level.*

It should mean that '*everything was excellent with wonderful service*'.

Comment: Thank you! I will use 'everything was high level. :-)

Comment: what was 'everything'.  Are you referring to a restaurant? a hotel? a beauty parlor?    Can you provide more details about the circumstances?